# How to get the latest records of each device in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

A stream table in DolphinDB "device" is used to store 3000 devices' real-time data.I would like to know the latest record of each device.The schema of device is as follows:

```
name      typeString typeInt
--------- ---------- -------
time      DATETIME   11     
device_id SYMBOL     17     
mem_free  LONG       5      
mem_used  LONG       5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from t context by device_id csort time desc
```

Comment: When providing an answer, you should also give some explanation and a reason why you believe your answer solves the problem Please read "How do I write a good answer?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer